# Adjustable current limiting in flyback converter using TL431

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, tl431

I'm building a SMPS and I would like to have a current limiting feature on the output. I'm trying to make a feedback loop using TL431, shunt resistor, optocoupler and a potentiometer, but no luck this far. I've managed to do fixed current limit, but adjustable one seems to be a bit more tricky. This is more or less what I came up with (it's only an idea diagram, but more o less this is what I did):

[image]

By the way, IC I'm using is UC3845. Anyone got idea how to do this? What I would like to have is something similar to way output voltage is regulated using TL431, but instead of output, I would like to regulate max current.

Comment: TL431 is a shunt regulator not SMPS. Without a schematic or at least a block diagram, how do you think folks will be able to help you?

Comment: @JackCreasey Yes, I know. Sorry for not adding a schematic, i'll fix it in a moment...

Answer (score 0):

On some converters it is possible to do current limiting by attaching the output of a current sensor to the feedback node of a converter through a diode.  Essentially what happens is that during each switching cycle, if the current exceeds the limit the FB pin is pulled high, which causes the converter to reduce its duty cycle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmhscF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also Linear Tech / Analog devices make several buck-boost type converter chips that have an adjustable current limit built in.  The limit is set by a voltage on the CTRL pin.  The voltage could be provided via a POT or a DAC.

You could try using the LT8390 or similar.
http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8390afa.pdf?domain=www.linear.com